# Efficient way to assign each element in a large vector to the number of repeats

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization, large-data

I have a vector of about 15 million integers (int32) containing about 1 million unique values. I would like to find an efficient method of counting the repeated integers and relating them back to the original vector so that I have a new vector containing counts for each element.

That's probably clear as mud, so here's a small example of what I'm looking for:

```
A      = [1 1 1 3 2 5 2 1 2 6];
...
result = [4 4 4 1 3 1 3 4 3 1];
```

My (impractically slow ) implementation is as follows (Note that in my version of matlab, hist does not work with integers):

```
A = randi(1e6,[15e6,1],'int32');
result = zeros(size(A),'int32');
[uniqueA,~,iuA] = unique(A);
counts = accumarray(iuA,1);
```

So far, so good: uniqueA contains a list of the unique elements of A, and counts contains a list of the corresponding number of each. This is pretty quick.

Next comes the slow part. I have tried the following to retrieve the indices of each element:

```
cellIndex = arrayfun(@(x) A == x, uniqueA,'UniformOutput',false);
```

but this runs out of memory (with 16 GB ram) and grinds to a halt when it starts swapping. To avoid this I tried looping over the unique elements (1 million), which is also slow:

```
for n = 1:length(uA)
    result(A == uA(n)) = counts(n);
end
```

I don't know how long this takes, because I've been waiting half an hour and it still isn't finished.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish my task efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried compiling the program to speed everything up? Matlab doesn't like for loops.

Comment: I haven't tried compiling, I usually try avoiding for loops instead if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach -

```
[unq,~,idx] = unique(A);
out = changem(idx,histc(A,unq),1:max(idx))
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     1     1     3     2     5     2     1     2     6
>> [unq,~,idx] = unique(A);
>> changem(idx,histc(A,unq),1:max(idx))
ans =
     4     4     4     1     3     1     3     4     3     1
```

---

Here's a simpler version -

```
[unq,~,idx] = unique(A);
counts = histc(A,unq);
out = counts(idx)
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     1     1     3     2     5     2     1     2     6
>> [unq,~,idx] = unique(A);
>> counts = histc(A,unq);
>> counts(idx)
ans =
     4     4     4     1     3     1     3     4     3     1
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply and the tip on histc vs. hist. I don't have the mapping toolbox, but I did try using this [octave changem code](https://github.com/assimiz/octave/blob/master/thesis/changem.m), and it seems to be a for loop just like mine. I'm not sure if the "real" changem code is the same, but have you tried it with 15 million elements in A? I'm still waiting for it to complete.

Comment: @Charbucks Check out the just added simpler version? Also, I am afraid I don't have the computing resources to handle millions of elements.

Comment: Thanks again, when I started reading the documentation of histc I just arrived at the same answer as your second (simpler version). Works just fine with my 15 million element example :)

Comment: @Charbucks Awesome! And the runtimes were?

Comment: the runtimes on my computer are in the 4-5 second range. Oddly, I get about a 1 second savings by using:

    uniqueA = unique(A);
    [bincounts,ind] = histc(A,uniqueA);
    result = bincounts(ind);

instead of finding the indices using unique. Not sure why, but both are working much better than the for loop (which I killed after almost an hour)

Comment: @Charbucks Ah you digged out some nice findings there! Good job! Well, loops are for *killing* anyway! Awesome!